# numpy, scipy, sklearn, or pandas to combine three 2D matrices in Python

Tags: arrays, numpy, pandas, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm using Python 2.7.6

I have Three 2-dimensional matrices with the same columns(n) and the same rows(m).  How can I collapse these 3 matrices into one megastructure that is the same indices and columns labels (m x n matrix).  Right now they are DataFrames in Pandas.

```
#Pseudocode
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DF_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
DF_2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
DF_3 = pd.DataFrame(data)

#I was thinking maybe a dot product like:

np.dot(DF_metNorm.as_matrix(),DF_cnvNorm.as_matrix(),DF_gexNorm.as_matrix())

#but np.dot() can only take two matrices
```

Is there any other way I can collapse these into one matrice that could include all of the data into a single metric using either `numpy` `scipy` `sklearn` or `pandas`? All values would be a scalar 2D matrix.

Comment: Whats wrong with a Panel? You could say `panel = pd.Panel({'df1' : DF_1, 'df2' : DF_2, 'df3' : DF_3})` and then have it together in one mega-structure with all of Pandas' awesome indexing and selection capabilities.

Comment: I've never known about tha tbefore. I just put it into one but I'm not sure if I can use this. The ultimate goal is to do some machine-learning on it so I need discrete values :/ Thanks for pd.Panel tho!  Seems really useful

Comment: In addition, dot product is [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). It is not a way of combining matrices in the sense you mean. It will multiply matrices together, same as doing 2x2=4, but for matrices, not scalars.

Comment: Experiment with Panels. They are like DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with a Panel? You could say

```
panel = pd.Panel({'df1' : DF_1,
                  'df2' : DF_2,
                  'df3' : DF_3})
```

and then have it together in one mega-structure with all of Pandas' awesome indexing and selection capabilities.